# $x^{1/2}-4x^{1/4}=0 \Rightarrow x = 0, 256$ - cannot arrive at this.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am asked to solve:

$x^\frac{1}{2}-4x^\frac{1}{4}=0$

The solution provided is x=0 and 256. I get stuck at $x^2-4x=0$:

$x^\frac{1}{2}-4x^\frac{1}{4}=0$

$(x^\frac{1}{2}-4x^\frac{1}{4})^\frac{4}{1}$ # raise both sides to $\frac{4}{1}$ as the reciprocal of $\frac{1}{4}$

$x^2-4x=0$ # where to go from here?

Perhaps my previous step was incorrect? For the first term in brackets, $x^\frac{1}{2}$ can be written $\sqrt{x}$ and then I'm raising to the power of 4 so $x^2$ since $(\sqrt{x})^2$ is just $x$ but I'm raising to power of 4 not 2 so $x^2$ for the first component.

For the second component since I'm raising to the reciprocal it cancels out to just $-4x$

Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at solutions 0 and 256?

Comment: Let $x^{1/4}= y$ and try solving.

Comment: $(a-4b)^4 \ne a^4-4b^4$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\sqrt[4]x=y,x=y^4$

$0=y^2-4y=y(y-4)$

$4^4=(4^2)^2=?$

Answer (score 5):

The fourth power of $a-b$ is not $a^4-b^4$, but $(a-b)(a-b)(a-b)(a-b)$.  That expands to a lot of terms.
However, you can write it as $a=b$, then fourth powers become $a^4=b^4$, so it works out okay.
You forgot to raise $4$ to the fourth power.

Answer (score 3):

Try letting $y = x^{1/4}$.

Then $y^{2} = x^{1/2}$, and the equation becomes

$$y^{2} - 4y = 0$$

upon which

$$y = 0; \,\, y = 4,$$

yielding

$$x^{1/4} = 0; \,\,\, x^{1/4} = 4;$$

Therefore,

$$x = 0; \,\,\, x = 4^{4}=256.$$